# Casting is not required when findViewById?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, casting

```
private void displayMessage(String message) {
        TextView orderSummaryTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.order_summary_text_view);
        orderSummaryTextView.setText(message); }
```

For this part of the code, according to one of the Udacity Android tutorial should be perfectly correct. But then the AS prompt me that the (TextView), which is the casting expression is unnecessary and when I remove it, it doesn't affect the function of the code and I can still setText on the next line. But WHY?

Can someone explain why is this? And I'm using AS 3.0 Canary 5, but as I know it doesn't make a difference.
Any help will be much appreciated. I'm a total newbie.

Comment: it s for latest development.

Comment: Better way to Generate `APK` use Cast for Wide Android Versions

Comment: @HamidRezaHeydari I think it won't be necessary as an APK is already compiled version

Answer (score 3):

Casting is not required since SDK 26, not because Android O.

So if you compile with SDK 26 you have this feature whatever your target or minimum version are.

> Note: In most cases -- depending on compiler support -- the resulting
>   view is automatically cast to the target class type. If the target
>   class type is unconstrained, an explicit cast may be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Since Android O it is not necessary to cast explicitly to a `View` object, the function automcatically does that for you, for more info check out **Google I/O 17**.

Comment: So you're saying Android O doesn't have to cast a view explicitly, but then my app targets Android 4.0.3 and above...

Comment: well check if its target level sdk build tools are set to be android O's, I don't know the version number since I have only been upto N, and it was said in google i/o

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int))

> In most cases -- depending on compiler support -- the resulting view is automatically cast to the target class type.

Answer (score 0):

The casting used to be necessary, while Android API was based on Java 6 (or 7).

I think lately, they improved several methods, like findViewById() with features from Java 8 and Generics, which allow the type of the result of a method "adopt" to the type of the variable, the result is assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Google I/O the casting in findViewById has been made optional in latest Android O to assist the developers.